# Rails escape characters for two layers of quotations

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, escaping

I'm trying to put my own percentage in a Bootstrap progress bar. The float is getting passed to the view perfectly fine, but for some reason the Bootstrap progress bar doesn't want to read it. I'm going to start by guessing I'm not properly escaping the `style` tag.

**The view:**

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="#{ <% @app.completion_status %> }" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: '#{raw(<%= number_to_percentage(@app.completion_status) %>)}';">
    <%= @app.completion_status %>%
  </div>
</div>
```

**A closer look:**

```
style="width: '#{raw(<%= number_to_percentage(@app.completion_status) %>)}';"

The value attempting to be passed and converted to a percentage is: `33.3333333333333` (one third)
```

**The controller:**

```
def set_completion
  @app = App.find(params[:id])

  @app.update_attribute(:completion_status,

  (((@app.elements.where(completion: true).count) / (@app.elements.count).to_f) * 100 )

  )
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first glance I see you are using ruby interpolation outside of the erb tags which could be the issue.  Edit:: Try below

```
style="width: <%= number_to_percentage(@app.completion_status) %>"
```

Below is one I just built so try to follow this and keep your interpolation inside the ERB tags!

```
<div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info progress-bar-striped"
 role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="<%=@email_usage%>" aria-valuemin="0"
 aria-valuemax="100" style="width: <%=@email_usage%>%">
```

Comment: @BrianKunzip No luck with `style="width <%= number_to_percentage(@app.completion_status) %>";` I'm afraid :/ This is quite confusing

Comment: Did you put a colon between width and your ERB tags?  Should be style="width: <%=      %>"

Comment: @BrianKunzip Finally got it working with `style="width: <%= number_to_percentage@app.completion_status %>"` Two questions though. 1: Did you mean to add the `%` outside the erb tag here: `style="width: <%=@email_usage%>%">`? 2: How does this work? I thought erb tags needed to escape quotations?

Comment: The % at the end is shown to the user exactly as a % because I wanted it to read something like "80%" whereas without that last % after my ERB tags it would have shown the user just a number like "80".  ERB can be put inside quote marks, you only need to escape quotes when you put quotes inside the ERB tags themselves.  Since these quotes are outside your ERB tags, escaping isn't necessary here.  Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried switching the **'** and **"**?

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="#{ <% @app.completion_status %> }" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style='width: "#{raw(<%= number_to_percentage(@app.completion_status) %>)}";'>
    <%= @app.completion_status %>%
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: no dice I'm afraid :/ I even changed the value of `@app.brief` (a string) to `60%` and got nothing.